# What are the websites to look for open source projects to work on?

Tags: open-source

I am currently working as a consultant but i found that i have not been doing coding for a very long time.

So i wonder if there are any other nice websites beside sourceforge.net which can allows me to do some coding.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net) - All sorts of open source software, from Linux to BSD to Windows.

[codeplex.com](http://codeplex.com) - Mainly Microsoft technologies-focused. This is where you'll find more of the .NET open source stuff.

Answer (score 3):

For general indexes to open source software, see [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/) and [Ohloh](http://ohloh.net/). The former is a classic index of open source software and the latter has statistics about the source code for each project, which might be handy if you want to judge how active a project is.

If you want to join easily, distributed revision control is nice. The big hosting sites for Mercurial ([Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/)), Git ([Github](http://github.com/)) and Bazaar ([Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/)) should give you plenty of projects to browse and, hopefully, contribute to :-)

Answer (score 2):

[OpenHatch (openhatch.org)](http://openhatch.org) is nifty (IMO) because:

- The site provides a number of "bite size" bugs from Free Open Source Software (FOSS) projects.
- There is a Map showing the registered users in your area, along with the langauges and projects they are involved in.
- The site provides an email forwarding address with rotating "anti-spam salt" by which other contributors may reach out to contact you.  (You may choose whether to use this, or provide an alternate means to contact you on the site.)

Answer (score 1):

Also, there's [Github](http://github.com/) and [Google Code](http://code.google.com/)

Comment: Hey, you copied my answer! :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I was editing my answer and added Google Code. When I submitted, I saw that you had posted it in the meantime...

Comment: That's okay, sorry... (it's just that I *have* seen that done where somebody edits their answer to include everything that a later poster did, just to get more votes).

Comment: @Zifre: copied? He just forked it ;)

Comment: i think the makers of the site encourage answer compilation.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/).

IMO, much nicer than SourceForge.

Answer (score 0):

How about Google [Summer of Code](http://code.google.com/soc/)?

If you're just looking for a small quick project, [Clusterify](http://www.clusterify.com/projects/).

Comment: 'currently working as a consultant' means probably not a student.

Comment: @Jimmy: it's still a good place to find active open source projects to contribute to (I'm sure they'd love contributers, whether you are a student or not, although don't expect to get paid for it by Google...)

Answer (score 0):

[Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/) is an other good collection of open source projects.
It provide details, timeline and notes.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of under served open source sectors that you can give your extra time to.

You don't have to do what everyone else is doing, take for example, the loads of time wasting CMS projects out there, while there seems to be no proper OCR in Java, and Jira is a great issue tracking system, no doubt, but its not open source, Bugzilla sucks, don't say Mantis, and Eventum is written in PHP(I'm a Java fanatic)

The best source for open source projects is of course sourceforge.net, Google code, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

We can not say that one website is better, it depends on the domain you work, so your best friend is well http://www.google.com with your keywords